# How to Add an image in an alertView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uiimageview, uialertview

I have three images

1. The first image is a background for alert view
2. The second image should inside the first image
3. The third image is an "Ok" button image (When I click it, I should go to the next page)

I would like to add these to a `UIAlertView`

Would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: I suggest to create a seperate container view, which can be easily customized according to your choice. You can then write the code to  go to your next page in the button click method.

Comment: you should create / find a custom alert view to achieve something like this. a thousand 'clones' are available on the net, but you can develop one for yourself, if it is worth to spent time on it.

Comment: please send me any code. i am new to IOS.

Answer (score 0):

**Prior to iOS7**:

You can add image to `UIAlertView` using

`[yourAlertView addSubview:<yourImageView>`;

---

**In iOS7+ you can not do this way.**

Please see this code available in [github](https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview) that adds image to `UIAlertView`.

Comment: `addSubview` on a `UIAlertView` object won't work in iOS7. Plus... imho, it's not a good practice anyways.

Comment: UIAlertView *successAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]; UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 10, 40, 40)];
NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"smile.png"]];
 UIImage *bkgImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
  [imageView setImage:bkgImg];
   [successAlert addSubview:imageView];
    [successAlert show];
  ; i am using this code but error coming in (title,message) why?

Comment: @janagowtham: what error? show the error, by doing edit in question with this code.

Comment: use of undeclared identifier title and message

Comment: Oh. You are learner. NO problem. The error is straight forward, you didn't declare these strings.

Answer (score 0):

I have done with following custom control. It might be what you are looking for :
https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview